# How do I get the value from a td tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have to get the inner value of a price:

```
<td align="center">Avg.Rate: $ 555</td>
```

How can do this using Nokogiri?

I tried:

```
price_list('td[text()*="Avg.Rate: $"]') do |price|
price.text.split('$').last.to_price
```

but did not get success.

Comment: Does the tag always have that inner text? Are there other tags like it you don't want? You need to show more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
price_list.at('td[text()^="Avg.Rate:"]')
```

Returns:

```
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8042e6b0 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8042e624 name="align" value="center">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80431fb8 "Avg.Rate: $ 555">]>
```

Grabbing the value:

```
price_list.at('td[text()^="Avg.Rate:"]').text[/\d+/]
=> "555"
```

If you're looking for a single, or the first, occurrence, use `at` or `at_css`. If you're looking for multiple occurrences, use `search` or `css`.

FYI: Nokogiri uses [jQuery compatible CSS selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: What non-standard jquery css selectors does nokogiri use?

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath string should use `starts_with`:

```
price_list.xpath('td[starts-with(text(), "Avg.Rate: $")]')
```